# .input-group-addon and .input-group-btn on same field have different sizes

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Im trieing to add an `.input-group-addon` and an `.input-group-button` to the same `.from-group` but unfortunatly the end up having different sizes when i combine them.

When I use them alone both work fine only side-by-side fails ugly.

[image: Screenshot of the Problem]

```
<div class="form-group publish_date">
    <label for="publish_date">Publish Date</label>
    <div class='input-group date datetimepicker'>
        <input type='text' class="form-control" name="publish_date" id="publish_date" value="" />
        <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="fa fa-calendar"></span>
        </span>    
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-warning" type="button"><span class="fa fa-fire" ></span></button>
        </span>    
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: works fine [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PboRpz). check your css.

Comment: I have the same problem, I think.  I have 2 input fields with appended `input-group-addon` on one and `input-group-btn` on the other.  Both addons have the same icon inside them, but the button is 1 pixel narrower and 2 pixels taller.